# Inverse Kaluza Klein metric

Tags: matrices, inverse

I am trying to verify that the inverse KK metric listed on the KK Wikipedia page is in fact the inverse of the KK metric.  To do this, I am multiplying them with matrix multiplication to see if the identity matrix results.  However, there is some discrepancy that I am unable to reconcile.  Also, I am 5D and my index counting convention goes from 1 to 5, with no 0.

The KK metric and inverse metric are:

$$
\Sigma_{AB}=\left(\begin{matrix}
-1-B_1B_1\chi^5 & -B_1B_2\chi^5 & -B_1B_3\chi^5 & -B_1B_4\chi^5 &  B_1\chi^5\\[8pt]
-B_2B_1\chi^5 & 1-B_2B_2\chi^5 & -B_2B_3\chi^5 & -B_2B_4\chi^5 &  B_2\chi^5\\[8pt]
-B_3B_1\chi^5 & -B_3B_2\chi^5 & 1-B_3B_3\chi^5 & -B_3B_4\chi^5 &  B_3\chi^5\\[8pt]
-B_4B_1\chi^5 & -B_4B_2\chi^5 & -B_4B_3\chi^5 & 1-B_4B_4\chi^5 &  B_4\chi^5\\[8pt]
B_1\chi^5 & B_2\chi^5 & B_3\chi^5 & B_4\chi^5 &  \chi^5\\[8pt]
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

and

$$
\Sigma^{AB}=\left(\begin{matrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 &0 & -B^1 \\[8pt]
0 & 1 & 0 &0 & -B^2 \\[8pt]
0 & 0 & 1 &0 & -B^3 \\[8pt]
0 & 0 & 0 &1 & -B^4 \\[8pt]
-B^1 &-B^2 &-B^3 &-B^4 &\eta_{\sigma\rho}B^\sigma B^\rho +\dfrac{1}{\chi^5}
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Then when I begin to multiply to get the first row, first column value of the product matrix, which should be 1 if it is to be the identity matrix, I get a sign problem.

Following the rules of matrix multiplication I get

$$
1+B_1B_1\chi^5+B_1\chi^5(-B^1)
$$

If I say that $B_1=B^1$ it will work, but actually using the regular formula

$$
A^\mu=\eta^{\mu\nu}A_\nu
$$

Then due to the single minus in the Minkowski signature, I should have $B^1=-B_1$ but then the one matrix is not the inverse of the other.

Is this my error or did the source of the inverse metric I found use sloppy labeling with the upper and lower indices?